# The equivalence of two definitions of the radical of the morphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, representation-theory

I am reading the book [Elements of the Representation Theory of Associative Algebras Volume 1](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/elements-of-the-representation-theory-of-associative-algebras/AA8066B5809D0F556A540400AD3A419C) written by Ibrahim Assen, Daniel Stimson and Andrzej Skowronski and the paper [on the radical of a category](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/9E41FD69E4DCE99B47D942C54C159CB6/S1446788700024071a.pdf/on-the-radical-of-a-category.pdf) written by G.M. Kelly.

Let $R$ be a finite dimensional $K$-algebra and we only consider $\mathrm{mod}~R$ whose objects are the finitely generated right $R-$modules.

In the above book and paper, they define the radical of $\mathrm{Hom}_R(A,B)$:

> $$\mathrm{rad}_R(A,B)=\{f\in \mathrm{Hom}_R(A,B)~|~1_A-gf ~~\text{is invertible}, \forall g\in \mathrm{Hom}_R(B,A)\}.$$

While I read the book [Representation Theory of Artin Algebras](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/representation-theory-of-artin-algebras/B7452F28EDADF450BF1059A6FB6D68A4), in this book, the authors define the radical of $\mathrm{Hom}_R(A,B)$:

> $\mathrm{rad}_R(A,B)=\{f\in \mathrm{Hom}_R(A,B)~|~hfg~\text{is not an isomorphism}, $
> $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{for any}~g\in \mathrm{Hom}_R(X,A) ~\text{and any}~h\in$ $ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\mathrm{Hom}_R(B,X) ~\text{with }~X~\text{is indecomposable in} ~\mathrm{mod}R\}$

For convenience, we denote the first definition and the second definition by $R_1$ and $R_2$, respectively.

I want to get the equivalence of two definitions of $\mathrm{rad}_R(A,B)$, i.e. $R_1=R_2.$

Here are my attempts:

> If we choose $f\in R_1$, we want to prove that $hfg$ is not an isomorphism.
> If not, there exits $\nu\in \mathrm{Hom}_R(X,X)$ such that $(hfg)\nu=1_X=\nu (hfg)$.
> Then we have $g\nu h\in \mathrm{Hom}_R(B,A)$ and, by the definition of $R_1$, $1_A-(g\nu h)f$ is invertible.
> Thus we have $s\in \mathrm{Hom}_R(X,X)$ such that $s(1_A-(g\nu h)f)$ $=1_A.$By the right multiplication of $g$, we have $s(1_A-(g\nu h)f)g=g.$
> Since $\nu (hfg)=1_X$,we get $g=0$. Then $hfg=0$ is not an isomorphism and it is a contradiction. Thus we prove $R_1\subset R_2.$

But I have no idea to prove $R_2\subset R_1$.

Any help and references are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!